# Ejecutar archivo y despues accionar boton con AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Buenas a todos tengo la siguiente duda a resolver tengo un select multiple de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el siguiente script

```
$('#link').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this),
                $select = $form.find('select'),
                links = $select.val();
        if (links.length > 0) {
            for (i in links) {
                link = links[i];
                window.open(link);
            }
        }
});
```

Cada opcion tiene su referencia(link), me gustaria saber si al dar click me ejecute primero un archivo con una consulta en SQL y despues me mande a la referencia.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var datos=$('#frmpsb').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"adline.php",
                data:datos,
                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){

                    }else{
                        alert('Linea no existente.');
                        window.location='index.php';
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Ese es el archivo "adline.php" que contiene mi consulta en SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con una funcion que invoque tu consulta, esperas las respuesta y luego redirecciona a tu referencia.
algo asi, despues de esta linea de codigo `link = links[i];` 
invoca una funcion. `myFunction(links[i]);`

```
`function myFunction(p1) {
var datos=$('#frmpsb').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"adline.php",
            data:datos,
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
       window.open(p1);
                }else{
                    alert('Linea no existente.');
                    window.location='index.php';
                }
            }
        });
}`
```